# python pandas - transform custom aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following data frame, of user activity across **2 days**:

```
    user    score
0   A   10
1   A   0
2   B   5
```

I would like to calculate the average user score **for that time** and transform the result to all the rows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'user' : ['A','A','B'],
                   'score': [10,0,5]})

df["avg"] = df.groupby(['user']).transform("sum")["score"]
df.head()
```

This could gives me the some of each user:

```
    user    score   avg
0   A         10    10
1   A          0    10
2   B          5    5
```

And now I would like to divide each score by the number of days (2) to get:

```
    user    score   avg
0   A         10    5
1   A          0    5
2   B          5    2.5
```

Can this be done on the same line where I calculated the sum?

Answer (score 1):

You can divide output `Series` by `2`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user' : ['A','A','B'],
                   'score': [10,0,5]})

df["avg"] = df.groupby(['user']).transform("sum")["score"] / 2

print (df)
  user  score  avg
0    A     10  5.0
1    A      0  5.0
2    B      5  2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

here you can something like that

```
df["avg"] = df.groupby(['user']).transform("sum")["score"]/2                                                                                                                                     

In [54]: df.head()                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[54]: 
  user  score  avg
0    A     10  5.0
1    A      0  5.0
2    B      5  2.5
```